# How to count checkbox checked and append that no divs to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check some check boxes from other div and count that checkboxes; And whatever the no of checkbox I want to append that nio of div to another div.

Comment: paste some html structure and whatever you have tried

Comment: use length *$('[type=checkbox]').length*

Comment: here i want count only checked checbox. not all checkbox.

Comment: var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("trainig_by_industry");
    document.getElementById("selectBox").innerHTML = "";
     for( i=0; i < checkBoxes.length;i++)
  { 
      if(checkBoxes[i].checked)
      { 
       total =total+1;
           
  
       if(total >3)
           {
                    alert("Please Select only three") ;
              return false;
      }
 else{
        
      }
           })

Answer (score 0):

Example:
You have the following checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Apples" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Bananas" />
```

Find the number of checkboxes using:

```
var $boxes = $('input[name=thename]:checked');
```

To find the length use :

```
$boxes.length;
```

Then use a loop to append number of divs:

```
$boxes.each(function(){
//   append divs here
});
```